# Problem with InDesign paragraph numbering

Tags: adobe-indesign, cs6, paragraph-styles

I realize this post may not be perfect for this SE forum, but seeing that it's a graphics editor I'm having problems with I'm thinking that maybe the right eyes will get to see it.

I'm having big problems with paragraph numbering in my InDesign document. I got handed the document by a colleague and found that all paragraph numbering was static text, which as you may know will make working with the document while keeping numbering updated very tedious..

So I started creating appropriate paragraph numbering styles and began converting. However, to my despair I see that on some pages the paragraph numbering isn't affected by the chapter numbering. So that the first paragraph in chapter 5 is numbered as paragraph 4.2.8, continuing the numbering from chapter 4....

Here's an illustration of the problem:

[image]

Does anyone please have any tips of what I could check to try and remove this error?

Comment: I haven't used Paragraph numbering to the extent you're using here (1.x.x), but have you tried placing the cursor on the first paragraph in chapter 5, and from the Paragraph pallette menu, choosing Restart Numbering?

Comment: @apex thanks for the tip! However, looking at the Paragraph palette I don't see the Restart Numbering option. It's not an option on the palette and I can't find it in the palette options menu. Do you know where to find it?

Comment: looks like you maybe found a work around for yourself, but if you want to try the **Restart Numbering**, here is [a screenshot](http://imgur.com/kzWrjVK) of where that option is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the paragraph numbering got updated to the correct chapter number if I duplicated the paragraph on that same page. Then the duplicate got the **5.2.1** numbering, which I guess will have to suffice, even though I could do without the **2** in the middle...